# fasttime for dates before 1970 returning NA

Tags: r, fasttime

Getting NA trying to parse this date:

```
fasttime::fastPOSIXct("1967-01-01", required.components = 3)
```

How come?

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in the `?fastPOSIXct` description

> fastPOSIXct converts timestamps in textual (string) form into POSIXct objects. It interprets sequences of digits separated by non-digits as a timestamp in GMT. The order of interpretation is fixed: year, month, day, hour, minute, second. Note that only true (positive) POSIX dates (**since 1970-01-01 00:00:00**) are **supported** and fastPOSIXct **accepts dates up to year 2199**.

Comment: `anytime::anytime("1967-01-01")` works just fine.  `anydate()` too, of course.  Both C++ based, and because they 'guestimate formats' both a little bit slower than `fasttime`, and more general.  (Disclaimer: I wrote the package.)

Comment: @Rafael yes, i do